# Bridging header error -- "xxx-Bridging-Header.h"file does not exit in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

How to resolve Bridging header error -- "xxx-Bridging-Header.h"file does not exit in SWIFT

Comment: This is an unusual post. You have posted an answer as a question. It would be better to edit this to look like  a question *as if you have this problem* then post the answer as an answer instead.

Comment: You are telling to whom ? in your comments ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the bridging header file name in the following location in Xcode.

Go to Project traget -> Build Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header

Set this as your Projectfolder/projectname-Bridging-Header.h

Answer (score 0):

I got an solution for bridging-header.h file does not exit. Just want to share, hope it may help others too.

Follow below steps:-

1. First of all delete all header file if you have implemented any.
2. Add new header file from the ios templet. Hope you know how to add any new file, just follow in same manner.
3. Now go to the buid setting and there search for objective-c bridging header, simply put the header file name with .h extension too.

please see the image how to add the file name in objective-c Bridging Header

[image]